Lebesgue measure of a set of limit points of a set?
Is there any subset of $\mathbb R^d$ that the set of its limit points has Lebesgue measure greater than zero?

For simplicity, let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $A=[0,1]\subset X$, then $A$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and so the closure of $A$ is $A$. Hence, for any sequence $(x_n){n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we know from basic analysis that $\lim{n\to\infty}x_n\in A$. Hence, if $L={x:\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x,(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset A}$ denotes the set of limit points, then in this example $\lambda(L)=\lambda(A)=1$ for $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps you are talking about more restrictive sets?

I think I should have asked the boundary points not the limit points.

Take the set $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$, it’s boundary is the set $[0,1]$.

Thank you so much. I'm not good at providing counter examples.

You are welcome! Don’t beat yourself up about it, practice makes perfect!
